# XNA C# Problem reading directory content

Tags: c#, xna

I've started developing of card game  with XNA but I had problems reading all the cards inside the Cards directory which is inside a Content.

I've tried following code:

```
string[] nomeCartas = Directory.GetFiles(@"Cards");
```

But with that I retrieved an error saying it could not be possible to find part of the path:

> Não foi possível encontrar uma parte
>   do caminho
>   'C:\Users\Serafim\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\JogoSuecaOnline\JogoSuecaOnline\JogoSuecaOnline\bin\x86\Debug\Cards\'.

I checked that path and it's wrong, the correct path should be:

> C:\Users\Serafim\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2010\Projects\JogoSuecaOnline\JogoSuecaOnline\JogoSuecaOnline\bin\x86\Debug\Content\Cards\

Is there any other way to read the Directory Content with XNA or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"Content\Cards");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] nomeCartas = Directory.GetFiles( Content.RootDirectory + "\\Cards" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] nomeCartas = Directory.GetFiles(
        Path.Combine(Content.RootDirectory, @"Cards"), @"*.xnb");
```